# laravel collections and chunking

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a golf app. I keep scores from rounds in a DB. I gran all the rounds for a particular user and am returned a collection (array:14). Each item consists of 190 items (array:190). The 190 items are the score data for a particular round of golf. Things like the score for each hole, the distance of each drive for every hole, etc.

What I am trying to do is get the average drive distance (all records with drive distance data totaled and divided by the # of opportunities.

The trick is I want to group these in groups of 5, 5, and 4. So I want the avg drive distance for the last 4 rounds, the previous 5 rounds, and the previous 5 rounds, etc.

I will plot these on a chart.

The problem I am having is accessing the items in the (array:190) after I chunk the initial collection:

```
$rounds = Rounds::roundsAll($user, 14); //grabs me 14 rounds for a user.
$chunks = $rounds->chunk(5); // gives me 3 collections of 4-5-5
```

I know that I need a nested loop like:

```
foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
foreach ($chunks as $key => $round) {
```

If I don't chunk it I can access the collection items like:

```
$round->$holedrivedistance
```

or

```
$round->scorecard->$holepar // I have defined these relationship 'scorecard'
```

How can I do this with the chunked collection so that I can iterate over each group adding the items I need to add. Then do the same for the next chunk.

RoundsAll returns a collection:

```
Collection {#277 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    0 => Score {#281 ▼
      #fillable: array:187 [▶]
      #dates: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:190 [▶]
      #original: array:190 [▼
        "id" => 15
        "created_at" => "2017-03-13 15:31:04"
        "updated_at" => "2017-03-13 15:31:04"
        "user_id" => 1
        "scorecard_id" => 42713
        "course_id" => 10555
        "club_id" => 9168
        "total_score" => 79
        "round_date" => "2017-03-09"
        "round_type" => 18
       ...
        "hole1_drive_distance" => 231
        "hole2_drive_distance" => 261
        "hole3_drive_distance" => 0
        "hole4_drive_distance" => 351
        "hole5_drive_distance" => 295
        "hole6_drive_distance" => 305
        "hole7_drive_distance" => 304
        "hole8_drive_distance" => 198
        "hole9_drive_distance" => 0
        "hole10_drive_distance" => 267
        "hole11_drive_distance" => 289
        "hole12_drive_distance" => 0
        "hole13_drive_distance" => 331
        "hole14_drive_distance" => 261
        "hole15_drive_distance" => 0
        "hole16_drive_distance" => 234
        "hole17_drive_distance" => 248
        "hole18_drive_distance" => 0
       ..
      ]
      #casts: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Score {#282 ▶}
    2 => Score {#283 ▶}
    3 => Score {#284 ▶}
    4 => Score {#285 ▶}
    5 => Score {#286 ▶}
    6 => Score {#287 ▶}
    7 => Score {#288 ▶}
    8 => Score {#289 ▶}
    9 => Score {#290 ▶}
    10 => Score {#291 ▶}
    11 => Score {#292 ▶}
    12 => Score {#293 ▶}
    13 => Score {#294 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Chunk returns these same collections grouped by 5-5-4

I need to iterate over the "hole#_drive_distance" => 261 items to total them then divided by number with a value to get an average. I do this for all the rounds successfully. The problem is I do not know how to do it so I am returned:

```
Chunk 1 = "AVG DRIVE"
Chunk 2 = "AVG DRIVE"
Chunk 3 = "AVG DRIVE"
```

Comment: Can you please add code for `roundsAll` and `chunk` method? And you have mistake there `foreach ($chunks as $key => $round) {` change to `foreach ($chunk as $key => $round) {`

Comment: RoundsAll just grabs all the rounds for a particular user. It returns a collection.